# How can I add metrics label to alert label

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

For example, I have a metrics `my_metrics{host="test_host"}`

and I want to let the alert rule of my_metrics contain the label host. Below is an example

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
# omitted
spec:
  groups:
    - name: my-alert
      expr: my_metrics > 0
      labels:
        severity: warning
        # host: {{$labels.host}} # I want to add host label in my_metrics to this alert
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything: it is done automatically.

For example, you can look at alerting rule provided in [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/#templating).

```yaml
  # Alert for any instance that is unreachable for >5 minutes.
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes."
```

Here metric `up` has label `instance` and when alert created, this label (as all the labels of metric) is copied to alert.